# Right way to handle "cron like" processes in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am planning for a nodeJS Application where the server has to handle time-based jobs. For example:

Job 1: Every 2 hours
Job 2: Every 5 minutes
Job 3: Every 10 days 
...

These jobs are saved in a database and there will be a lot of jobs - it could be a millions of these.

So now is my question which is the right way in nodeJS to handle this ? There are a lot cron packages for cron like processes but I thought its maybe "to much" for this.

I was thinking about .... Timeouts! Right - timeouts.

This is the schema I was thinking of:

```
var job = getJob();
var executeInMs = getMSUntilExecute(job);
setTimeout(function(){handle();}, executeInMs);
```

With this schema it really could be that there are a million timeouts running at the same time in my application.

The question now is: Is this a Server-Killer or is this the right way to handle this ?

Comment: Definitely a server killer - namely, there is no way to distribute it to more than one server (no persistence), and all timeouts reset on a server restart or redeploy.

Comment: What about using a queue instead of a database?  There are a few that let you set the timeout, distribute across several worker nodes, etc.